# Ignore service implementation file while executing swagger code gen

Tags: swagger, codegen

I am trying to implement my rest services using jersy and documentation using swagger. Once model is generated using code gen and added logic in my service implementation class. Now if I want to regenerate model, is there any parameter to pass to code-gen to ignore/skip  service implementation class or list of classes which are configured to ignore. Because not to loose logic implemented in service class.

Please suggest me good practices of swagger.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to swagger too, but the [code-gen docs on github](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) explain that you can put a .swagger-codegen-ignore file in the root of your output folder to specify the files or directories that you don't wan't to overwrite.